# Getting a value from a PHP object

Tags: php

I have an object that is returns as below.

```
print_r($all->getInfo());
//returns the following on browser.
User Object ( [_name:User:private] => Kanye, West [_email:User:private] => kanye@hotmail.com)
```

I would like to read the name and email and set it to two seperate variables like below.

```
$email = $all->getInfo()._email;
$name= $all->getInfo()._name;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So look at the methods that are defined in your `User` class, there's probably a `getName()` and a `getEmail()` method (or similar)... but you have the code for the class, we don't

Comment: you can define getter method to access private member in your "User" class

Answer (score 0):

You can do somtething like this to get access to private proprites.

```
class sampleClass {

private $property1 = 'name';
private $prooerty2 = 'email';

public function getProperty1(){
return $this->property1;
}

public function getProperty2(){
return $this->property2;
}

public function setProperty1($name){
}
$this->property1 = $name;
}

public function setProperty2($email){
$this->property2 = $email;
}

}
```

To get properties:

```
$classy = new sampleClass();

echo $classy->getProperty1;
echo $classy->getProperty2;
```

To set properties:

```
$classy->setProperty1('name1');
$classy->setProperty2('email2');
```

You can also use magic methods for __get and __set, [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the values, you can either set them to `public` (which may not be the best solution depending on what you're trying to do), or create the `__get()` magic method

```
class foo
{
    private $value = "foo";
    private $value2 = "foo2";

    public function __get($name)
    {
        switch ($name)
        {
            case "value";
            return $this->$name;

            default:
            return null;
        }

    }
}

class bar
{
    private $value = "bar"; 
}

$f = new foo;
$b = new bar;

echo "Result:" . $f->value . "<br/>";
echo "Result:" . $f->value2 . "<br/>";
echo "Result:" . $b->value . "<br/>";
```

this yeilds

```
Result:foo
Result:
E_ERROR : type 1 -- Cannot access private property bar::$value -- at line 31
```

Of course, you can also create a function such as `get_name()` but then you'd have to do that for every `private` property you want to access.

If you want to control what is and what is not accessible from the `__get()` method, you can add some logic. This way you know that if you are trying to access a property, it's in the `__get()` method and not have to try to figure out what the method name is.

Comment: true, but if u have one point of access like getName and setName, it`s safer, cuz u are giving access to only those properties that u want, and on conditions defined in set / get

Comment: Personal preference, but I find it cleaner to put logic in the `__get()` method to determine if something is okay to be accessed. You could also throw your own exception if something is trying to access something that shouldn't be and trap errors, or even log them.

Comment: True it all depends of what u want to try to archive if i have class that have 10 properties, give ability be set/get to only 2 of them, then creating 4 methods sounds better for me. On the other hand __get __set methods are much more efficient in other situations. Ohh and i feel that ppl should first learn about doing they own set/get to step to __set/__get, personall preference too i suppose :)